# How To Tell What Version Of SMB Is Being Used?

Tags: macos, smb, cifs, afp

I recall from a while ago, I used a command that enabled me to see what version of SMB (CIFS/SMB1/SMB2) active mounts were using.

For the life of me I can't remember the command nor can I find it anywhere online.

What is the command line command to display active mounts and their negotiated connection method in OS X?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

First establish a connection to a shared volume, and then, enter the following command in Terminal:

smbutil statshares -m /path/to/mount

The -m switch means that you will specify the mount point. You can also use the -a switch to specify all.

Comment: And with the argument -a you can list all mounted shares:
`smbutil statshares -a`